# How do I find out the ENV['RACK_ENV'] on the ruby irb?

Tags: ruby, heroku, openshift, rack

I have the following line in my gemfile.

```
if defined? ENV['RACK_ENV'] == 'production' then gem 'pg' else gem 'sqlite3' end
```

On [Heroku](http://heroku.com) it uses the `pg` gem as it sees it's in production and on my computer it uses the `sqlite` gem. However on [Openshift](http://openshift.com), it's saying that the pg gem isn't found so it can't run the app, so obviously `ENV['RACK_ENV']` doesn't think it's in production and maybe on development instead.

How do I find out the variable of `ENV['RACK_ENV']` on irb, rack or ruby the command line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Heroku the `RACK_ENV` environment variable was set for you, this isn't going to be the case on your local machine (or apparently Openshift). In Ruby reading an environment variable that isn't set returns `nil`.

```
$ export ANY_ENV=foo
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> puts ENV['ANY_ENV']
foo
=> nil
irb(main):002:0> puts ENV['ANOTHER_ENV']

=> nil
irb(main):003:0> ENV['ANOTHER_ENV'].nil?
=> true
```

On Openshift you'll need to set `RACK_ENV` to `production` via `rhc env set RACK_ENV=production -a YOUR_APP_NAME`

They offer three ways of viewing environment variables:

- Add an export statement to the `App_Name/.openshift/action_hooks/build` file, then run `git push`. The variables are listed in the Git output and start with remote: `declare -x`.
- Access the application with SSH and run the `env` command at the shell prompt.
- Use the `rhc env list -a <appname> command`

See https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-environment-variables.html for more details on setting environment variables on Openshift.